# How to delete image file in folder using JQUERY without using PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

Who knows that JQuery code can do unlink code like PHP without using PHP file? For example, I want to delete or unlink aaa.jpg file from the folder

```
www.abc.com/images/aaa.jpg
```

when I click delete button.

Comment: Without PHP specifically?  Or, do you mean doing it only with a browser HTTP connection?

Comment: You cant access the file system with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is built upon javascript and is a browser scripting language. You can't delete/create a file. If you are building an app that needs access to filesystem using javascript. Check out  https://electronjs.org/